# What is the most efficient way to convert JSON with multiple objects to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have Json responce like below.

```
[
    {
        "week":1,
        "win":10,
        "lose":[
            {
                "week":2,
                "count":1
            },
            {
                "week":3,
                "count":0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "week":2,
        "win":7,
        "lose":[
            {
                "week":3,
                "count":1
            },
            {
                "week":4,
                "count":3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "week":3,
        "win":8,
        "lose":[
            {
                "week":4,
                "count":1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to convert this into array  with "win" counts and  "count" inside the  "lose". Is there any good way to achieve this without using forloops?

**Expected output:**

```
[

[10,1,0],

[7,1,3],

[8,1]

]
```

Since im doing this in the front end whats the best way to do this?

Comment: First you start with `JSON.parse`

Comment: And then there are **hundreds** of answered questions on how to map arrays (including object arrays) to other forms. Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution with two `map()` operations:

```js
const data = [{
  "week": 1,
  "lost": 10,
  "recovery_timespan": [{
    "week": 2,
    "count": 1
  }, {
    "week": 3,
    "count": 0
  }]
}, {
  "week": 2,
  "lost": 7,
  "recovery_timespan": [{
    "week": 3,
    "count": 1
  }, {
    "week": 4,
    "count": 3
  }]
}, {
  "week": 3,
  "lost": 8,
  "recovery_timespan": [{
    "week": 4,
    "count": 1
  }]
}];

const result = data.map(({lost, recovery_timespan}) => [
  lost,
  ...recovery_timespan.map(({count}) => count)
]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: arguments destructuring is a quite verbose and anti-DRY pattern, a simple `data.map(a => [a.lost, ...a.recovery_timespan etc` would be shorter and much easier to read.